# Replacing old urls with new ones

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string from a database which contains some urls. I'm trying to replace the old urls with the new ones. Because the string that contains the urls is formatted `{s:5:"hello"}`, I also need to replace the old string lengths with the new ones.

I tried

```
var url    = "http://localhost/arearaf";
var text   = "somelongstring; 35; '%site_url%'; s:46:\"%site_url%/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png\"; someotherlongstring; s:54:\"%site_url%/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo-150x150.png\";";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"s:\d+:\" + "\"%site_url%(.*?)\";", "s:" + (url.Length + "$1".Length) + @":\" + "\"" + url + "$1" + @"\" + "\";");
```

which resulted in

```
"somelongstring; 35; '%site_url%'; s:26:\"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png\"; someotherlongstring; s:26:\"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo-150x150.png\";"
```

but should be

```
"somelongstring; 35; '%site_url%'; s:60:\"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png\"; someotherlongstring; s:68:\"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo-150x150.png\";"
```

`"$1".Length` obviously doesn't return `"/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png".Length`. How can I get the length of the capture group for each replace? Also am I handling the problem correctly? If not, what do I do?

---

<sup>Doesn't this format `{s:5:"hello"}` have a name or something? I can't google it. The closest thing I could find is CMS which stands for Content Management System, I guess? Still, not enough.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the match evaluator and modify the code the following way:

```
var url    = "http://localhost/arearaf";
var text   = "somelongstring; 35; '%site_url%'; s:46:\"%site_url%/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png\"; someotherlongstring; s:54:\"%site_url%/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo-150x150.png\";";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "s:\\d+:\"%site_url%(.*?)\";", m =>
        $"s:{url.Length + m.Groups[1].Value.Length}:\"{url}{m.Groups[1].Value}\";");
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => somelongstring; 35; '%site_url%'; s:60:"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo.png"; someotherlongstring; s:68:"http://localhost/arearaf/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/logo-150x150.png";
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/9S1I5k)

**Pattern** (`s:\d+:"%site_url%(.*?)";`):

- `s:` - a substring `s:`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits (compile with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` to only match ASCII digits)
- `:"` - a `:"%site_url%` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0 or more chars other than a newline (pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` if you need to match newlines, too)
- `";` - a substring `";`

The match evaluator passes the match object to the interpolated string literal:

- `$"` - interpolated string literal start
- `s:` - literal `s:`
- `{url.Length + m.Groups[1].Value.Length}` - interpolated part where the URL length and Group 1 value length are summed and cast to a string
- `:\"` - `:"` substring
- `{url}` - `url` var value
- `{m.Groups[1].Value}` - Group 1 value
- `\";` - a `";` substring
- `"`  - end of the string literal.

For older environments with no interpolated string literal support, use `string.Format`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "s:\\d+:\"%site_url%(.*?)\";", m =>
  string.Format("s:{0}:\"{1}{2}\";", 
    url.Length + m.Groups[1].Value.Length, url, m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express and getting this error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type". What am I missing?

Comment: 4 Client Profile. Should I change it?

Comment: Ok, looks like the lambdas are OK, but your IDE does not support interpolated string literals. Change the `$""` into a `string.Format`. See my latest edit.